# Favicon stopped working in Chrome all of the sudden

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, favicon

I have this code used in my WP theme:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fav.ico?<?php echo date('U'); ?>">
```

and not cache it, since `<?php echo date('U'); ?>`. My problem is, and my client reported it to me today, that the favicon stopped showing only in Chrome. I tried moving it to the root of the page, adding `type`, removing the "refresh" hack, changing name to `favicon.ico` and even adding additional `link icon` for PNG image. Nothing helps. Yes, I've been trying to

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/fav.ico?v=2">
```

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have messed up with the code then use plugins like http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-favicon/

This plugin will override your theme favicon functionality and will help you with your desired result.

This should help.